# Radius of circumscribed circle of triangle as function of the sides

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

Given the length ot the sides $a , b$ and $c$  of $ \triangle ABC$.

What is the length of the radius of the circumcribed circle?

After some formula substitution I came to the monster formula:

$$ \frac {a b c}{\sqrt{2a^2b^2+2a^2c^2+2b^2c^2-a^4-b^4-c^4}} $$

Can this formula be simplified?

Comment: Multiply and divide by $\sqrt{2}$, then write the denominator as sum of squares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will notice that the expression inside the square root sign can be factorized using the difference of two squares:
$$
2a^2b^2+2a^2c^2+2b^2c^2-a^4-b^4-c^4 = 4a^2b^2 - (a^2+b^2-c^2)^2 
$$
$$
= (c^2-(a-b)^2)((a+b)^2-c^2)
$$
$$
=(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(b+c-a)(c+a-b)
$$
if you set s=$\frac{a+b+c}2$ then this expression becomes
$$
16s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)
$$
which you may recognize from a formula giving the area of a triangle in terms of the lengths of its three sides